# ASsign IJavaScriptExecutor executescript result to local variable

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to assign value from IJavaScriptExecutor to specific local variable?

```cs
IWebElement element= getelement(rowNumber);
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Utility.Driver;
js.ExecuteScript("ko.dataFor(arguments[0]).Title()", element);
```

result of this js is a string. I want to assign that string to specific variable and return it as a result of a method. 
Is there any way to do it.

I have tried

```
text=js.ExecuteScript("ko.dataFor(arguments[0]).Title()", element).ToString();
```

but it is obvious why that cannot work.
Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `return` in your JavaScript code.

`text=js.ExecuteScript("return ko.dataFor(arguments[0]).Title()", element).ToString();`